# Docker apt-get update fails during building phase

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, ubuntu-16.04

Dockerfile first lines

```
FROM ubuntu:22.10
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update
```

bash script

```
cargo clean
docker build -t (name) .
```

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server where rust (and thus cargo) and docker are installed correctly. However, when I execute the bash script with sudo I get the following error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.032MB
Step 1/13 : FROM ubuntu:22.10
 ---> 692eb4a905c0
Step 2/13 : ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 91f5113c2f8f
Step 3/13 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in 4af7c0d85fd7
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports InRelease
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Reading package lists...
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100
Unable to find image 'marshal:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for marshal, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Docker with various ways (apt, snap, etc.), I tried docker system prune, changing the sources list, creating a new server and starting over, etc. but the problem remains.

ChatGPT tells me there is a problem with kinetic (Ubuntu 22.10), but doesn't offer me any help that solved the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I belive that's because Ubuntu 22.10 has reached [End of Life on July 20 2023](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/14/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-20-2023/).

Better to use a LTS version. e.g. Ubuntu 22.04